# Combining settings in enumitem package

Tags: enumitem

I have trouble combining settings of an indent and label customization in this package. 
I want my list to look like this: [image]

Right now I only managed to adjust it like this, with the basic style of numeration - "1.".

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[wide, labelindent=0pt] 
\item blahblah 
\item blahblah
\end{enumerate}
```

Where to put the label customization **[(1)]** to make this work?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The image you show seems to have each item starting with a displayed equation.  If that is what you want, the answer will be different than if you really want just text in the items.  Please clarify.

Comment: Can you please show a larger sample of the text you want to reproduce? As @barbarabeeton says, this seems more like numbered equations than an enumerated list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A small variation of @Bernard answer (+1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, label =(\arabic*)]
\item \hfil$r_1,,r_2,\dots, r_{\varphi(m)} $

-- \lipsum[66]
\item \hfil$\rho_{k} \equiv r_{k}\pmod{m} $

czycli
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) I discover this use of `\hfil` as an alternative to `\makebox` for centring!

Answer (score 6):

Here is a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, label =(\arabic*), parsep = 1ex]
\item \makebox[\linewidth]{$r_1,,r_2,\dots, r_{\varphi(m)} $}

\lipsum[11]
\item \makebox[\linewidth]{$\rho_{k} \equiv r_{k}\pmod{m} $}

\lipsum[11]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]